# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Studio installation fails in Eclipse Kepler

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

Installation of Worklight Studio 6.1 fails in Eclipse "Kepler" for JEE:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: IBM jQuery Mobile Tools 6.1.0.00-20131126-0630 (com.ibm.webtools.jquery.tools.feature.feature.group 6.1.0.00-20131126-0630)
  Missing requirement: com.ibm.webtools.jquery.core 1.1.0.v20131126_0602 requires 'bundle org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.emf.core [1.4.1,2.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Rich Page Editor - jQuery extensions 2.0.100.v20131126_0602 (com.ibm.etools.rpe.jquery 2.0.100.v20131126_0602)
    To: bundle com.ibm.webtools.jquery.core [1.0.0,2.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: jQuery Web Tools 1.1.0.v20131126_0602 (com.ibm.webtools.jquery.feature.feature.group 1.1.0.v20131126_0602)
    To: com.ibm.etools.rpe.jquery [2.0.100.v20131126_0602]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: IBM jQuery Mobile Tools 6.1.0.00-20131126-0630 (com.ibm.webtools.jquery.tools.feature.feature.group 6.1.0.00-20131126-0630)
    To: com.ibm.webtools.jquery.feature.feature.group [1.0.0,2.0.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Works for me in Eclipse Java EE **4.3.1 ("Kepler" SR1)**. Make sure that is the version of Eclipse you are using.

Worklight 6.1 supports:

- Eclipse Java EE 4.2.2 ("Juno" SR2)
- Eclipse Java EE 4.3.1 ("Kepler" SR1)

If you have installed anything else in Eclipse prior to installing Worklight, please note this in your question; it may have caused some dependency change.

Comment: i kept trying to install again and again, and after a few (a lot of) tries, it succeeded. Perhaps it could be the eclipse web site or my enterprise proxy that was not reliable at that moment...

Comment: That's always a possibility. :)

Comment: Is Eclipse Luna supported by Worklight Studio 6.1?